# Orient db: cant create index

Tags: grails, indexing, orientdb, graph-databases, tinkerpop

Hi im getting the following error when trying to create an index using orient db with grails via tinkerpop api:

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with name __@recordmap@___idx-myindex already exists.

I have a method which I call first to drop the indexes:

```
 Index<Vertex> theIndex = graph.getIndex(indexName, Vertex.class)
 if (!theIndex) { // The index is always null when searching for idx-myindex
     log.warn "Index ${indexName} does not appear to exist"
     return
 }
 graph.dropIndex(indexName)
 commitTransaction()
```

And then a method which I call after to create the index:

```
 Index<Vertex> theIndex = graph.getIndex(indexName, Vertex.class)
 if (theIndex) { //index is always null when searching for idx-myindex
     log.warn "Index ${indexName} already exists"
     return
 }
 graph.createIndex(indexName, Vertex.class) //throws the error
 commitTransaction()
```

Im using orient db 2.1.16, and this problem is only arising now after upgrading from 1.6.6.

Also when i list the indexes in the embedded graph I can see there are two indexes

1) __@recordmap@___myindex

2) myindex

Why are there two indexes in the graph db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For now my work around is to specifically drop the index with recordmap prepended to it until this issue is fixed:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4730